# Invalid value for property <position>

Tags: javascript, json, perl, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to combine perl and Javascript to map IP address Lat/Long locations to a Google Map using the Google Maps API v3.  What I'm getting back is in the marker, I'm getting the error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <position>: 43.073052,-89.40123`

My code is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use CGI qw(:standard);
    use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
    use CGI::Session ( '-ip_match');
    use SOAP::Lite;
    use lib '/home/schreiber/perl5/lib/perl5';
    use JSON qw(encode_json);

    $session = CGI::Session->load();
    $q = new CGI;
    my $soap = SOAP::Lite
        -> uri('http://v1.fraudlabs.com/')
        -> proxy('http://v1.fraudlabs.com/ip2locationwebservice.asmx')
        -> on_action(sub { join "/", "http://v1.fraudlabs.com", $_[1] });

    $license = "<removed>";

    #if($session->is_expired) {
    #  print $q->header(-cache_control=>"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    #  print "Your session has expired.  Please login again.";
    #  print "<br/><a href=\"../login.html\">Login</a>";
    #} elsif($session->is_empty) {
    #  print $q->header(-cache_control=>"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    #  print "You have not logged in";
    #} else {
      print $q->header(-cache_control=>"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");

      open (IPF, "/home/access_log");
      @incomingarray=<IPF>;

      $i = 0;
      foreach $pair(@incomingarray) {
        ($ip, $rest) = split(/ - - /, $pair);
        $incomingarray[$i] = $ip;

        chomp $ip;
        $i++;
      }

      close (IPF);

      my %hash = map { $_, 1 } @incomingarray;
      my @distinctIP = keys %hash;

      $j = 0;
      my @iplocation;
      foreach (@distinctIP) {
        my $method = SOAP::Data->name('IP2Location')->attr({xmlns => 
        'http://v1.fraudlabs.com/' });

        my @params = SOAP::Data->name('inputdata' => \SOAP::Data->value(
        SOAP::Data->name(IP=>$_),
        SOAP::Data->name(LICENSE=>$license)
        ));

        my $result = $soap->call($method => @params);
        $lat = $result->valueof('//LATITUDE');
        $long = $result->valueof('//LONGITUDE');

        push(@iplocation, "$lat,$long");
      }

      my $json = encode_json(\@iplocation);

    #  print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
      print '<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.49, -91.30),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\'map_canvas\'),
                myOptions);

            var coord_data = new Array();
            coord_data = '.$json.';

            var marker;
            for (var i = 1; i < coord_data.length; i++) {
               console.log(coord_data[i]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord_data[i]),
        map:map
      });

              marker.setMap(map);
            }
          }

          function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement(\'script\');
            script.type = \'text/javascript\';
            script.src = \'//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize\';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
          }

          window.onload = loadScript;
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
      </body>
      </html>
      ';
    #}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign the position here --

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:coord_data[i],
    map:map
});
```

-- you give it a raw JSON object, but it's expecting a google.maps.LatLng object.  You will want to assign it like this--

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord_data[i].lon,coord_data[i].lat)
```

See here also for some good samples of the Gmaps API usage: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/

Comment: Thank you.  It's no longer giving me the error, but it's also not adding the marker to the map.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's just a matter of checking your syntax now (I suspect the issue is just Javascript syntax).  I can't say exactly what's happening as I'm not fluent in Perl.  As a test I copied your HTML to a text file and loaded it in Chrome, testing with Firebug.  It worked with the marker after I changed 2 lines of code: 
    coord_data = [{ lat: 44.49, lng: -91 }]; 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord_data[i].lat, coord_data[i].lng),